# JavaScript variable.id as button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

I have a `div` definition by variable:

```
var div_btnlft = document.createElement('div');
div_btnlft.className = "shiftbutton shiftbutton-left";
div_btnlft.id=this.id+"_shiftbutton-left"; //this.id carries view id
```

I want to use this unique ID definition as button selector in code

```
$('#'+this.id+"_shiftbutton-left").click(function()
{
    console.log("Left click");
}
```

Doesn't work.
Any clues will be appreciated 
Thanks. 
UPDATE 
With users posting about dynamic nodes not working for buttons I beg to differ

```
    var div_btnrgt = document.createElement('div');
             div_btnrgt.id = "shiftbutton-right";         

        $("div#shiftbutton-right").click(function(){
            }
```

The latter works fine .I was looking for the same ID name with a dynamic name .

Comment: Could you please provide any error messages? "Doesn't work" is not much to work with.

Comment: make a minimal demo of this happening

Comment: Why not `$(div_btnlft).click( ... )`? http://jsfiddle.net/rjgop06w/

Comment: @MelanciaUK I cant use the classname , as I have a number of such buttons on screen( belogning to different view parents ). So ID is the only unique thing about the button . Hence I wanted to know how can I select the button using ID only .Thanks for your response

Comment: hmm it seems like you're trying to dynamically add variable ids to the buttons. Why not give the button element a unique ID and then create one $("div.button").click(function(e){}); and in that method use $(e.currentTarget).id or some property to determine which button was clicked and do your stuff from there. This helps you write less code, reduce and reuse ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically created elements will not work with `click` events, you have to use `$("STATIC-PARENT").on("click", "dynamic-element", function(){....});`

```
$(document).on("click", '#'+this.id+"_shiftbutton-left", function()
{
    console.log("Left click");
}
```

OR

```
$(STATIC PARENT HERE).on("click", '#'+this.id+"_shiftbutton-left", function()
{
    console.log("Left click");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .The parent is also dynamically generated . The document is super parent (parent of the parent widget of button ) . But $(document).on("click"....) doesnt seem to work . Nor does $(this.view).on("click"....this.view is dynamic , so thats understandable .So what can be the possible resolution ?

Comment: If you include more code or create a http://jsfiddle.net we will be able to help you better

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .click function only attaches elements that are in the DOM at render time, you need to use .on()

documentation here: 
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Do you mean to imply $('#'+this.id+"_shiftbutton-left").on(function()
{
    console.log("Left click");
} That doesnt work for me . But thanks for your response .

Comment: if you would have read the documentation for on, you would have found out that it's called like this:   $(parent-selector-non-dynamic).on("event-name", child-element-selector-that-is-dynamic, function () { console.log("left click"); } );